# JetStream: How to make Push Subscription with Durable consumer? (i get "No interest")

Tags: c#, nats.io, nats-streaming-server, nats-jetstream

I try to make Durable and Delivery consumer, but I get "No Interest" as result.

1. It is "Active" When I create PushSubscribeOptions like this:

   PushSubscribeOptions pso = PushSubscribeOptions.Builder()

   ```
            .WithDurable(options?.DurableName)
             .WithStream(options?.StreamName)
            .Build();
        IJetStreamPushAsyncSubscription sub =
            _js.PushSubscribeAsync(options?.Subject, someHandler, true, pso);
   ```
2. It is "No interest" when I use this code:

   PushSubscribeOptions pso = PushSubscribeOptions.Builder()

   ```
            .WithDurable(options?.DurableName)
            .WithStream(options?.StreamName)
            .WithDeliverGroup(options?.DeliveryGroup)
            .Build();

        IJetStreamPushAsyncSubscription sub =
            _js.PushSubscribeAsync(options?.Subject, someHandler, true, pso);
   ```

I am confused.

How to make Push subscription with Delivery+Durable options?

Answer (score 0):

Start the subscriber before you create the push consumer. At least in go, the no-interest is only an optimization (why transmit on a topic no one is subscribing on), and there it will start to push as soon as the is a subscriber ON THE PUSH TOPIC